# Puzzle.. solving product of values in array X

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

Can you please help me solving this one?

You have an unordered array X of n integers. Find the array M containing n elements where Mi is the product of all integers in X except for Xi. You may not use division. You can use extra memory. (Hint: There are solutions faster than O(n^2).)

The basic ones - O(n^2) and one using division is easy. But I just can't get another solution that is faster than O(n^2).

Comment: can you rephrase the question?  Don't know why division is needed... is it to find the cumulative product?

Comment: This question is usually asked to be done in O(n) without division.

Comment: Note that using division does not work if the list contains a zero.

Answer (score 14):

Let `left[i]` be the product of all elements in `X` from `1..i`. Let `right[i]` be the product of all elements in `X` from `i..N`. You can compute both in `O(n)` without division in the following way: `left[i] = left[i - 1] * X[i]` and `right[i] = right[i + 1] * X[i]`;

Now we will compute `M`: `M[i] = left[i - 1] * right[i + 1]`

Note: `left` and `right` are arrays.

Hope it is clear:)

Comment: You could perhaps add that `left` and `right` are meant to be arrays.

Comment: @Svante OK, I will add that:)

Comment: Hi Petar. I'm having difficulty understanding your solution. Could you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: @ebae Hi! You want M[i] to be the product of all elements in X except the i-th element. So let `left[i]` = the product of all elements in X with indices < i and `right[i]` = the product of all elements in X with indices > i. Then M[i] = left[i] * right[i]. I have described above how to precompute the `left` and `right` arrays in linear time.

Comment: Hmm, Petar,
istn' the solution supposed to have a runtime better than O(n^2)?? Your solution solve M[i] in O(n) time agreed.
Now if you are going to populate M, you have to do O(n^2). Which is too slow. Right?

Comment: No, it won't take O(n^2). It'll take O(n) time. It computes the arrays left and right in O(n) time each (and thus O(n) time combined), and from there it's a linear operation to compute M (a constant time operation per position). A sum of a constant number of O(n) operations is itself O(n)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in Python.  I did the easy way with division to compare against the hard way without.  Do I get the job?

```
L = [2, 1, 3, 5, 4]

prod = 1
for i in L: prod *= i
easy = map(lambda x: prod/x, L)
print easy

hard = [1]*len(L)
hmm = 1
for i in range(len(L) - 1):
    hmm *= L[i]
    hard[i + 1] *= hmm
huh = 1
for i in range(len(L) - 1, 0, -1):
    huh *= L[i]
    hard[i - 1] *= huh
print hard
```

Comment: The method with division will fail if the list contains a zero.

Answer (score 1):

`O(n)` - http://nbl.cewit.stonybrook.edu:60128/mediawiki/index.php/TADM2E_3.28

two passes -

```
 int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    int array[] = {2, 5, 3, 4};
    int fwdprod[] = {1, 1, 1, 1};
    int backprod[] = {1, 1, 1, 1};
    int mi[] = {1, 1, 1, 1};
    int i, n = 4;
    for (i=1; i<=n-1; i++) {
        fwdprod[i]=fwdprod[i-1]*array[i-1];
    }
    for (i=n-2; i>=0; i--) {
        backprod[i] = backprod[i+1]*array[i+1];
    }
    for (i=0;i<=n-1;i++) {
        mi[i]=fwdprod[i]*backprod[i]; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`O(nlogn)` approach:

```
int multiply(int arr[], int start, int end) {
    int mid;
    if (start > end) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (start == end) {
        return arr[start];
    }
    mid = (start+end)/2;
    return (multiply(arr, start, mid)*multiply(arr, mid+1, end));
}

int compute_mi(int arr[], int i, int n) {
    if ((i >= n) || (i < 0)) {
        return 0;
    }

    return (multiply(arr, 0, i-1)*multiply(arr, i+1, n-1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old but very cool, I've been asked this at an interview myself and seen several solutions since but this is my favorite as taken from 
http://www.polygenelubricants.com/2010/04/on-all-other-products-no-division.html

```
static int[] products(int... nums) {
       final int N = nums.length;
       int[] prods = new int[N];
       java.util.Arrays.fill(prods, 1);
       for (int // pi----> * <----pj
          i = 0, pi = 1    ,  j = N-1, pj = 1  ;
         (i < N)           &          (j >= 0) ;
          pi *= nums[i++]  ,  pj *= nums[j--]  )
       {
          prods[i] *= pi   ;  prods[j] *= pj   ;
          System.out.println("pi up to this point is " + pi + "\n");
          System.out.println("pj up to this point is " + pj + "\n");
          System.out.println("prods[i]:" + prods[i] + "pros[j]:" +  prods[j] + "\n");
       }
       return prods;
    }
```

Here's what's going on, if you write out prods[i] for all the iterations, you'll see the following being calculated

```
prods[0], prods[n-1]
prods[1], prods[n-2]
prods[2], prods[n-3]
prods[3], prods[n-4]
.
.
.
prods[n-3], prods[2]
prods[n-2], prods[1]
prods[n-1], prods[0]
```

so each prods[i] get hit twice, one from the going from head to tail and once from tail to head, and both of these iterations are accumulating the product as they
traverse towards the center so it's easy to see we'll get exactly what we need, we just need to be careful and see that it misses the element itself and that's where
it gets tricky.  the key lies in the

```
pi *= nums[i++], pj *= nums[j--]
```

in the for loop conditional itself and not in the body which do not happen until the end of the 
iteration.  so for 
`prods[0],` 
it starts at 1*1 and then pi gets set to 120 after, so prods[0] misses the first elements
`prods[1],` it's 1 * 120 = 120 and then pi gets set to 120*60 after
so on and so on

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution in Python: Easy way but with high computational cost may be?

```
def product_list(x):
ans = [p for p in range(len(x))]
for i in range(0, len(x)):
    a = 1
    for j in range(0, len(x)):
        if i != j:
            a = a*x[j]
        ans[i] = a
return ans
```